# Problemas con Navegacion Anidada en React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Hola tengo un problema espero me puedan ayudar un poco, es con la navegacion anidada en **React Native**, tengo varios Stack Navigation dentro de un Drawer Navigation

*Codigo de Drawer*

```
    <Drawer.Navigator
      drawerType="front"
      screenOptions={CustomScreenOptions}
      drawerContent={(props) => <CustomDrawerComponent {...props} />}
    > 
      <Drawer.Screen name="Dashboard" component={DashboardStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Leads" component={LeadsStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Comisiones" component={ComisionesStack} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notificaiones" component={NotificationsStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
```

Visualizando la pantalla de 'ComisionesStack' **no puedo navegar en las demas Screens del Stack** por ejemplo de *ComisionesHome* a *DetallesCliente* haciendo uso de  `const navigation = useNavgation();` me lanza el siguiente error `ReferenceError: Property 'routes' doesn't exist` al ejecutar en un boton `navigation.navigate('DetallesCliente')`

*Codigo de ComisionesStack*

```
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          gestureHandlerProps: false,
          gestureEnabled: false,
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen name="ComisionesHome" component={Comisiones_View} />
        <Stack.Screen name="DetallesCliente" component={DetallesClienteView} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
```

Sin embargo si puedo navegar atravez de las screens definidas en el Drawer estando el Stack por ejemplo `navigation.navigate('Dashboard')`.

No esta tomando el navigation correctamente, algun aporte de alguien al que ya le haya sucedido al similar.